# Set id by foreach range

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
public IActionResult DismissContestants()
{
    var contestants = _contestantService.GetList(a => a.JuryId == null).Data;
    var juries = _roleService.GetList(x => x.RoleId == 4).Data;
    var d = contestants.Count / juries.Count;
    int sayac = 0;

    foreach (var contestant in contestants.Take(juries.Count))
    {
        foreach (var jury in juries)
        {
            contestant.JuryId = jury.UserId;
            sayac++;
        }

        _contestantService.Update(contestant);
    }

    return RedirectToAction("GetList", "SiteSetting");
}
```

I want to dismiss contestants to juries but not random. Let's say we have 8 contestant and 2 juries, first four contestant going to take first jury id and last four going to take last jury id. That's I want to do but at this code contestants get first jury's id.

Comment: Quite a lot wrong in this code... Try to step through with a debugger and see what is actually happening. For example you only iterate over the first few contestants... Why do you need to iterate over each jury for each contestant?

Comment: I already check values with debugger. First jury comes and set his id to contestants after leave loops. I don't know where I make mistake

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you would want something like

```
var juryIndexForContestant = (ContestantIndex * JuryCount) / ContestantCount
```